# Auto-scale Number.prototype.toFixed() digits to first non-repeating digit?

Tags: javascript

Round percentages are meaningful to humans only between 1% and 99%. Once you get above 99% or below 1%, to be meaningful often requires greater precision (e.g. how many 9s pure is this?).

It would be helpful to the human mind to see as many digits as needed to gain a sense of how close to 0% or 100% the number is, but to show round numbers when it's between 1% and 99%. I'm using `Number.toFixed()`. Is there a way to **auto-scale to the first non-repeating digit** rather than supplying a fixed # of digits?

Examples:

**High auto-scales to first non-9**

```
99.9135335 => 99.91%
99.9953 => 99.995%
99.999923153 => 99.99992%
99.999999999999999992342 => 99.999999999999999992%
```

**Between 1% and 99%, round numbers**

```
98.2353 => 98%
55.0234 => 55%
1.53243 => 1%
```

**Low auto-scales to first non-0**

```
0.932 => 0.9%
0.013523 => 0.01%
0.00344 => 0.003%
0.0000001343 => 0.0000001%
```

Comment: toFixed() requires a fixed number of digits. I want it to be automatic - as many digits as needed to get to a non-repeating digit.

Comment: well, to as many digits as javascript precision allows then.

Answer (score 1):

A small approach by using a logarithm of ten for getting relevant digits.

```js
function format(f) {
    const d = f >= 1 && f < 99 || !f || f === 100
        ? 0
        : -Math.floor(Math.log10(f < 1 ? f : 100 - f));

    return `${f.toFixed(d)} %`;
}

console.log(format(99.9135335)); // 99.9% should be 99.91
console.log(format(99.9953)); // 99.995%
console.log(format(99.999923153)); // 99.99992%
console.log(format(99.999999999999999992342)); // is 100 %
console.log(format(98.2353)); // 98%
console.log(format(55.0234)); // 55%
console.log(format(1.53243)); // 1%
console.log(format(0.932)); // 0.9%
console.log(format(0.013523)); // 0.01%
console.log(format(0.00344)); // 0.003%
console.log(format(0.0000001343)); // 0.0000001%
console.log(format(0)); // 0 %
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Excellent! I did not remember what log10 did.